Database UTF-8 encoding problem when trying to retrieve data from spring boot application
My Oracle Database does not support utf-8 encoding, however some tables column values still consists of utf-8 characters. it is inserted using N text literal. So my goal is to be able to filter this utf-8 characters from spring boot application. Currently when I try to filter data utf-8 characters are read as '?' question marks in database. my initial thought to fix was to achieve following oracle query in my Spring boot application
SELECT * FROM entity WHERE text like N'%utf-8-characters%'  (this query works correctly on database)
I was unable to find hql code for replacing N string literal
  @Query("SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE " + "(:filter is null or :filter = '' or "
      + "LOWER(e.text) LIKE CONCAT('%',LOWER(:filter), '%')  "
      + "ORDER BY e.modifiedDate DESC")
  Page<Entity> findAllByOrderByModifiedDateDesc(@Nullable String filter, Pageable pageable);

I also tried native query, it worked if I hardcode filter for example, but could not pair with incoming argument.
works but hardcoded -> WHERE text LIKE N'%აა%'
invalid -> WHERE text LIKE N:filter
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM entity WHERE text LIKE CONCAT('%',CONCAT(:filter,'%')) ORDER BY modified_date",nativeQuery = true)
Page<Entity> findAllByOrderByModifiedDateDesc(@Nullable String filter, Pageable pageable);

adding encoding properties wont work because as I said database itself does not reads utf-8 characters
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@111.11.1.111:1111:DB?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
server.servlet.encoding.charset=UTF-8
server.servlet.encoding.enabled=true
server.servlet.encoding.force=true


neither does beans like CharacterEncodingFilter.

Which encoding are you using in the database. And if your database doesn't support UTF-8 or any Unicode encoding, the LIKE, LOWER, etc. makes little sense: the engine cannot properly do the job and it may corrupt characters, e.g. if it think some accented letter are in Latin1 (or derived), it may lower, so corrupting the UTF-8 encoding

for normal characters database uses CL8MSWIN1251 encoding. and for national characters with N prefix it uses UTF-16.

but the thing is even with native query I am unable to use N preffix.
query ->
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM entity WHERE message_prefix LIKE '%' || N:text || '%' ORDER BY modified_date",nativeQuery = true)
following exception ->
JDBC exception executing SQL [select * from (SELECT * FROM entity WHERE text LIKE '%' || N? || '%' ORDER BY modified_date) where rownum<=?]

First you have to add property to recognized nationalized fields in database:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_nationalized_character_data=true

then all I had to do was not to use oracle functions. I dont know why but
       @Query("SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.text LIKE %:messagePrefix% ")

this query works correct with utf-8 characters.
however when using oracle functions like Concat it did not work
@Query("SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.text LIKE CONCAT('%',:text,'%') ")
Even for @Query("SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE Lower(e.text) LIKE %:text% ") it does not work

@Query expects JPQL queries, not native queries, that why.
